# Count power of big numbers and then apply modulo on this numbers

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have this example code in which I have very big numbers as you see. The problem is that when I use this algorithm for some small numbers, it works well, but when I use it for big numbers like in this example, this algorithm is so slow.

Can you tell me why this algorithm is so slow for that big numbers? How can I make it faster?

```
n = 11698030645065745910098695770921
e = 9569991810443215702618212520777
d = 7874909554574080825236064017913
m = 104228568138
m = int(m)
e = int(e)
n = int(n)
def preparation(m, n):
    block_lenght= len(str(n)) - 1
    m = [str(m)[i:i+block_lenght] for i in range(0, len(str(m)), block_lenght)]
    return m

def encrypt(m, n, e):
    m = preparation(m, n)

    power = [int(i) ** e for i in m]

    modulo = [i%n for i in power]

    total_sum = sum(modulo)

    return total_sum

m = encrypt(m, n, e)
print("m = ", m)
```

Comment: Not worth an answer yet but the pow builtins takes up to 3 arguments and actually perform what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please explain what you are calculating. Is this an algorithm like RSA? MathJax is available, if you need to type mathematical notation.

Comment: Yes, its part of code for RSA encrypting, this "n", "m", "d" and "e" are generated from another part of code. This "m" is converted text message.

Answer (score 1):

Your spelling of `length` is unconventional, and will cause errors.

Calculating the full result will generate a large number, slowing computation.  It's better to reduce the partial results as you compute the power, and keep the partial result mod *n* - you'll probably want to use **binary exponentiation** instead of the `**` operator so that you can apply the modulus to the intermediate results.

I don't see what `m = int(m)` and similar lines are intended to achieve - probably worth a comment there.

How is the final (partial) block handled?  That seems to be missing altogether.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid the amount of duplicated/useless operations**

The function `int` is called on integers which is useless.

The `str` function is called many times on the same inputs which can be avoided with temporary variables.

You iterate (indirectly) 3 times over the result of `preparation2`, this could be done with a single operation.

At this stage, you can write something like:

```
def preparation2(m, n):
    n_str = str(n)
    m_str = str(m)
    block_len = len(n_str) - 1
    return [m_str[i:i+block_len] for i in range(0, len(m_str), block_len)]

def encrypt2(m, n, e):
    return sum((int(i)**e) % n for i in preparation2(m, n))
```

**Builtin**

The [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) builtins takes up to 3 arguments and actually perform what you are trying to achieve in a much more efficient way.

```
def encrypt2(m, n, e):
    return sum(pow(int(i), e, n) for i in preparation2(m, n))
```

**Final code and benchmark**

I wrote the following code to test the original code and the improved code and ensuring that the behavior is not broken on inputs of increasing sizes:

```
def preparation(m, n):
    block_lenght= len(str(n)) - 1
    m = [str(m)[i:i+block_lenght] for i in range(0, len(str(m)), block_lenght)]
    return m

def encrypt(m, n, e):
    m = preparation(m, n)

    power = [int(i) ** e for i in m]

    modulo = [i%n for i in power]

    total_sum = sum(modulo)

    return total_sum


def preparation2(m, n):
    n_str = str(n)
    m_str = str(m)
    block_len = len(n_str) - 1
    return [m_str[i:i+block_len] for i in range(0, len(m_str), block_len)]

def encrypt2(m, n, e):
    return sum(pow(int(i), e, n) for i in preparation2(m, n))


import time

TEST_CASES = [
    (116, 956, 787, 10),
    (1169, 9569, 7874, 10),
    (116980, 956999, 787490, 104),
    (1169803, 956999, 787490, 104),
    (11698030, 9569991, 7874909, 1042),
    (11698030645, 95699918104, 787490955457, 10422),
    (116980306450657459, 956999181044321570, 787490955457408082, 104228568),
    (11698030645065745910098695770921, 9569991810443215702618212520777, 7874909554574080825236064017913, 104228568138),
]
SEP = "      "
print("Comparison", SEP, "Original solution", SEP, "Improved solution")
for (n, e, d, m) in TEST_CASES:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    out = encrypt(m, n, e)
    time_sol1 = time.perf_counter() - start

    start = time.perf_counter()
    out2 = encrypt2(m, n, e)
    time_sol2 = time.perf_counter() - start
    if out != out2:
        print("Different outputs", SEP, out, SEP, out2)
        break
    else:
        print("Times", SEP, time_sol1, SEP, time_sol2)
```

And the results:

```
Comparison        Original solution        Improved solution
Times        4.408881068229675e-05        2.5639310479164124e-05
Times        0.00031274929642677307        1.0897871106863022e-05
Times        0.587213734164834        2.9506627470254898e-05
Times        0.5985749792307615        2.992432564496994e-05
Times        62.84936385508627        3.45488078892231e-05
```

Then the original code becomes too slow to have results while the improved code still runs instantly....

**Making things clearer**

In could be an idea to make the behavior of `preparation` clearer, with a better name and with a clearer signature:

- as we do not really need `n` but just its length, we could provide directly the required `block_len`
- we could provide the stringified version of m directly.

You get something like:

```
def split_str_in_blocks(s, block_len):
    return [s[i:i+block_len] for i in range(0, len(s), block_len)]

def encrypt2(m, n, e):
    block_len = len(str(n)) - 1
    return sum(pow(int(b), e, n) for b in split_str_in_blocks(str(m), block_len))
```

Comment: So I modified my code as you adviced me, but its still slow

Comment: @Brian Oh, I am surprised... Did you notice that the functions names are not exactly the one from your code ?

Comment: Yes, in a minute I modify my question to current form

Comment: Any other advices? My current code you can see in modified top question.

Comment: @Brian I've updated my answer to add more details

Comment: I update my code, but there is another error, you can check it on my new question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668450/algorithm-for-encrypt-decrypt